# Query for Access database to retrieve data?

Tags: sql, database

I have data in the access database.

Please suggest a query so I can see the result table data.
I want to show data from this table.

**My table:**

[image]

**Result table:**

[image]

i am trying

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(AIR),
    allotedinstitute,
    course,
    alloted category
FROM
    table
WHERE
    allotedinstitute = allotedinstitute 
    AND
    alloted category = alloted category;
```

Comment: Your SQL is invalid: the `allotedinstitute = allotedinstitute` expression will match all rows.

Comment: Also, you need to escape column-names when they contain spaces or special characters, so it should be `[Alloted category]`, not `[alloted category]`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
MAX(Rank),
[Alloted Quota],
[Alloted Institute],
Course,
[Alloted Category]
FROM  Table
WHERE  
[Alloted Institute] = N'Govern...'  
GROUP BY 
 [Alloted Quota],
 [Alloted Institute],
 Course,
 [Alloted Category]
```